# Xcode Crashes after a changed Provisioning Profile

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, crash-reports

Xcode crashes after I changed the Provisioning Profile and code signing. Now when  I try to open the project, Xcode immediately crashes. Do I have to change the profile from my developer account?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get why it crashed but I would recommend to reinstall Xcode (to the newest version). Then reinstall the provisioning profiles and certificates.